# Wamp server online modeconflict with router

Tags: wamp, port, wampserver

I'm trying to setup my local wamp server online using its online/offline feature.

Every time I head to my IP address, I get redirected to my router's config page instead of wamp homepage.
[image]

I tried changing these lines in `httpd.config` file at `C:\wamp\bin\apache\appache2.4.9\conf\`

```
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
```

to

```
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:8080
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
Listen [::0]:8080
```

but my ip (the one that shows at http://whatsmyip.org) still redirects to my router's config page. Even if I write `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080` i get `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`
EDIT: Adding some info

- Router info:
  http://www.zyxel.com/products_services/amg1202_t10b.shtml?t=p
- Dynamic IP (That's my ISP plan)

Answer (score 1):

Your router is at a lower level. Some type of remote config/help/whatever is turned on in your router. Since it is at a lower level then your Apache server, it will always grab the packets with destination port 80 first.

You need to figure out what "feature" is turned on in your router.

```
Internet -> Router -> Apache
```

Your apache is probably just fine.

Regards to your router...since it's not showing what you need. You could factory reset it and make sure you set it up with "advanced view" selected. You should have all your options to set port-forwarding correctly

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZ0zoZ_pbUM

Comment: Any clue where can I check that? I'm using w7, no tweaks, its a damn good fresh installation.

Comment: http://www.techspot.com/guides/287-default-router-ip-addresses/

You need to login to your router by its internal IP address, that list should have your model...if you can't find it...cmd prompt ->ipconfig -> default gateway. probably something like http://192.168.1.1

Comment: I edited my question, added the router model... By the way, I always accessed it via 192.168.1.1, I can also access it going to whatmyip.org and using THAT ip on my browser, it also redirects to my router's page.

Comment: @frondor Unless you're able to login and change your settings you're out of luck. The only other thing I can suggest, if you're just doing some testing is try to hit it from your interal ip. 192.168.1.whatever:8080

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to give your PC a static IP address and add that address to your router's DMZ but without knowing your router's make/model I cannot give you step by step instructions.

It's basically a port forwarding issue. Check you have forwarded the correct ports on your router.

Comment: Also check Windows/Linux and 3rd party firewalls (all firewalls).

Comment: I edited my question, added the router model...
The problem is that my ISP provides dynamic IPs, and my router's control panel is really limited, I think I need some time of "master password" to access the full configuration settings... I'm kinda screwed :D

Comment: @frondor You are correct, you need to be able to login and change the settings.

Comment: @JoeSwindell Look at this, http://i.imgur.com/EUXwcjV.png I can login but I don't have any settings for port forwaring... This is so awkward

Comment: If you can figure out how to get to the advanced setup page in the router...page 48 is all you need from the manual

ftp://ftp.zyxel.com/AMG1302-T10B/application_note/AMG1302-T10B_1.00.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Most home/office routers will do this.

It's because most do not have a feature called `LoopBack` either available or turned on.

Without this feature the router has no way of spotting that the ip address you are using in your browser is in fact your routers WAN IP Address so it assumes you are addressing your routers httpd server and launches the routers Admin panels. ( yup there is an web server running in your router )

With `loopback` enabled it would, loop you back into your internal network.